# I don't have writing access to a subdirectory in /

Tags: command-line, permissions

I have a server running under Debian wheezy. I want to create a directory in `/`. I can't without running `sudo mkdir myDirectory`. Once in `/myDirectory`, I can't write anything or create a repertory. I tried to run as root: `chmod -R /myDirectory 775`, but in vain. I am sure that I am missing something obvious, but I can't find what. Could somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: There are some good solutions here, but generally the only place for directories owned by a user is in the user's home directory. There are obviously exceptions, but generally the reason you can't create files under root without root permissions is so normal users can't mess with the system. If you give some information on what you are trying to achieve by doing this, we can always suggest alternatives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, it seems that you haven't understood the basics of file permissions.

`ls -ld /myDirectory` shows you that `root` is both the owner and the group of the new directory. I.e. if you access the directory then you do that as `other`. And you have defined (`775`) that `other` have **no write permission** in this directory.

Probably the best solution is to change the owner:

```
sudo chown $USER: /myDirectory
```

Answer (score 3):

If the directory is owned by root and you set the mode 775, of course you can't write anything there -- the first two 7's apply to the owner and the group, and you probably aren't (*shouldn't be*, actually) in root's group.  The 5 applies to everyone else, and it is a combination of read (4) and execute (1).  No write (2)! Notice 4+1+2 = 7.

Most likely what you want to do is change the *ownership* of the directory (`chown`).  Alternately, you could just change the *group* (`chgrp`) to one you are a member of.

Comment: Just as an added note to the OP: Do **not** 'fix' this by adding the 'w' to the others permissions.